# Animate transitions of DialogFragment using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-transitions, android-navigation-graph, bottomsheetdialogfragment

Is animating transitions of DialogFragment supported by Navigation Component?

My dialog:

```
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/loginBottomSheetDialog"
        android:name="com.app.tlbx.mvvm.bottomsheetdialogs.authenticationbottomsheetdialog.LoginBottomSheetDialog"
        android:label="LoginBottomSheetDialog">

     <action
          android:id="@+id/action_loginBottomSheetDialog_to_verificationBottomSheetDialog"
          app:destination="@id/verificationBottomSheetDialog"
          app:popUpTo="@id/loginBottomSheetDialog"
          app:popUpToInclusive="true"
          app:popEnterAnim="@anim/no_animation"
          app:popExitAnim="@anim/no_animation"
          app:enterAnim="@anim/no_animation"
          app:exitAnim="@anim/no_animation"/>
</dialog>
```

`anim/no_animation`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     //Empty
</set>
```

When I navigate to the destination declared in the action, its default animations are being displayed instead of the one defined in `@anim/no_animation`.